# Upgrade to CBA after 2010 to 2013 Migration

Tags: 2010, 2013, claims-based-auth, upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading an Intranet publishing site from 2010 to 2013. I have the new 2-server farm up and running. My next step is to detach/attach the 2010 databases to the new 2013 environment.

My new 2013 Web Application is showing Claims Based Authentication as the default provider for SharePoint - 80. How do I convert to CBA (Claims Based Authentication) after migrating the databases? The following TechNet link did NOT help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

Doing this in my current production environment is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create a new classic-mode web application in 2013 (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276326.aspx).  Then use the article you mentioned in your question to convert the web application to claims-mode after you attach your content database.

Comment: Thanks John, I was able to create the Web app with classic-mode authentication :-)